# OpenFrameworks, with OpenCV, VS2013 setup

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, openframeworks

So I am a total newbie (and you may have guessed because this is my first post/question here). I have a working OpenCV 2.4.8 install with Windows 8.1, running Visual Studio 2013 Express. I have downloaded OpenFrameworks for Windows ZIP archive and unzipped it. Now, I am stuck with the fact that I know nothing about what next to do. The setup guides on OpenFrameworks are how to install the IDE, not OF. The tutorials that are available are also more geared toward Macs, which I don't have access to for development purposes.

So, in short, I need some help in getting OpenFrameworks installed within Visual Studio 2013 EXPRESS, for my robotics high school robotics team, FRC.

By the way, has anyone successfully exploited the available resources from both, OpenCV and OpenFrameworks? If so, please let me know how I can get started integrating both together! ;)

So here's a little bit about me environment:
5 OSes (WIN8.1,WIN7, 250GB HDD, WIN7 32GB SSD, Ubuntu, under Wubi 30GB vDISK, Ubuntu, under Wubi 24GB vDISK), 6GB RAM, 1.5GB RAMDISK (can be disabled), i3-2367 (very slow) with CPU GOVERNOR PERFORMANCE under Ubuntu.

Thank you for your time and help, and peace!

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/pull/2571) can be helpful.

Comment: I had already looked at that GitHub page. However, I am stuck in getting the initial install down. I guess I can go through and fix the errors I get after I get the initial install. BTW, I also have VS2010 exp and VS2010 ultimate, Student.

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://www.users.muohio.edu/jamiespa/teaching/ECE_387/Bob__Harrison__David__Mark-May_25_2011/aa79352b927facb1904c0d3014c7c025.html)? This guide is for MS VS2010, and including initial installer's link for windows.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to use with visual studio 2010, download the respective package from the below link.

http://openframeworks.cc/download/older.html

the latest version supports 2012 or above, which is 0.8 (I say, prefer the latest one, as it has good examples to start with)

After the installation, if you go to the respective directory of openframeworks, you will find a folder named project generator, use it to generate your project file. follow the below link to get an idea.

http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/introduction/002_projectGenerator.html

As you are interested in opencv, you can use the addon available in openframworks ofxopencv and use couple of examples in examples folder to get used to its interface.